# Regex to find multiple words

Tags: regex

Regex to find the text exactly as `A23 Z 12345` from the multiple lines using the regex. If I found the above result, its TRUE.

Input:

```
For the following policy A23 Z 12345 will be cancelled.
```

Expected Output:

```
A23 Z 12345
```

Comment: Is there a question in your question? :)  Right now it reads as a sequence of rather cryptic statements.

Comment: `.*(A23 Z 12345).*` ?

Answer (score 1):

Expression for exactly capturing that is quite simple. You only might want to add a capturing group around it without any other boundary and it would do so:

```
(A23 Z 12345)
```

[image]

You can use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/wqIoJQ/1/) to test/edit/update/change that expression, if you wish. You can add more boundaries to it, if you want.

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

```js
const regex = /(A23 Z 12345)/gm;
const str = `Any other chars that might be A23 Z 12345 and any other chars after A23 Z 12345 Any other chars that might be A23 Z 12345 and any other chars after A23 Z 12345 Any other chars that might be A23 Z 12345 and any other chars after A23 Z 12345 `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'Any other chars that might be A23 Z 12345 and any other chars after';
 const regex = /(.*)(A23 Z 12345)(.*)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$2");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: should we not add word boundaries `\b` at the beginning and the end too ?

Answer (score 0):

A Python solution for this problem using re library:

```
x = 'For the following policy A23 Z 12345 will be cancelled.  A23 Z 123456r will be cancelled.'
print(re.findall('A23 Z 12345', x))

['A23 Z 12345', 'A23 Z 12345']
```